# Creating two virtual networks in Vagrant

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant

I need 2 virtual vagrant networks talking to each other via one 'gateway'. I'm modeling multi-tier application that would be deployed on many servers. I need smth like that:

```
db-server--                                  --db-server
           |                                |
            --distributor **** distributor--  
           |                                |
app-server-                                  -app-server
```

`db-server`, `app-server` and `distributor` make private network. This network should be accessible only from `distributor` of second virtual network. I have `Vagrantfile`:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  # db-server
  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.hostname = "db"

    db.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "1" ]
      v.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "512" ]
    end

    db.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.11"
  end
  # application server
  config.vm.define "app" do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "app"

    app.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "1" ]
      v.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "512" ]
    end

    app.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.12"
  end
  # distributor server
  config.vm.define "distributor" do |distributor|
    distributor.vm.hostname = "distributor"

    distributor.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "1" ]
      v.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "512" ]
    end

    distributor.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.13"
  end
end
```

How should I configure my `distributor`? The only way I found is adding smth like `config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.10.14"` to it.
But what IP should I assign to distributor 2? Can I specify second network machines in the same `Vagrantfile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extrapolate from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31349342/441652) (additional details there):

```
 db-server-1=[192.168.1.3]             [192.168.2.3]=db-server-2
             [192.168.1.1]=distributor=[192.168.2.1]
app-server-1=[192.168.1.5]             [192.168.2.5]=app-server-2
```

### Working `Vagrant` file

Copied & pasted:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.provider "libvirt"

  config.vm.define "rhel7_minion" do |rhel7_minion|
    rhel7_minion.vm.box = "uvsmtid/centos-7.1-1503-gnome"
    rhel7_minion.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', disabled: true
    rhel7_minion.vm.network 'private_network',
        :libvirt__network_name => 'primary_vagrant_private_net',
        ip: '192.168.1.2',
        :libvirt__netmask => '255.255.255.0',
        :libvirt__forward_mode => 'route',
        :libvirt__dhcp_enabled => true
  end

  config.vm.define "rhel5_minion" do |rhel5_minion|
    rhel5_minion.vm.box = "uvsmtid/centos-5.5-minimal"
    rhel5_minion.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', disabled: true
    rhel5_minion.vm.network 'private_network',
        :libvirt__network_name => 'secondary_vagrant_private_net',
        ip: '192.168.2.3',
        :libvirt__netmask => '255.255.255.0',
        :libvirt__forward_mode => 'route',
        :libvirt__dhcp_enabled => true
  end

end
```

- The `distributor` can be your physical host.
- You get **the top half** of the diagram by renaming `rhel7_minion` => `db-server-1` and `rhel5_minion` => `db-server-2`.
- You get **the bottom half** of the diagram by copying & pasting (& modifying names with IPs) to add servers `app-server-1` and `app-server-2`.

Answer (score 0):

In your Vagrantfile App, Db and Distributor all are on the private network so all three can talk to each other. You can put app on private network, db on public network and distributor on both public network and private network. This configuration allows distributor to talk to app via private network and to db via public network but app and db can not talk to each other because app is on private network and db is on public. Now, install some king=d of program on distributor that can act like a proxy between app and db.

[Network configuration for vagrant boxes](http://www.brownfort.com/2014/09/network-configuration-vagrant-boxes/)